# Can I implement gradual consent with Azure AD Applications?

Tags: azure-active-directory

The Facebook app platform supports [a "gradual consent" model](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices#onlyask) - whereby an app can be written to request consent from the user for resources only when they are needed. For example, an app may want `public_profile` all the time, but for a certain function the app also needs `user_birthday`. The app can be created in such a way that it prompts the user for consent to `public_profile` as soon as it is installed, but only prompt for `user_birthday` when the user actually uses the function that requires it. If the user never uses that function, the app never prompts for permission to access `user_birthday`. Permission is granted to the users resources gradually and only when they are needed - hence, "gradual consent".

Can I implement this pattern with Azure AD Applications? For example, let's say I have a web app with an optional feature that accesses the Microsoft Graph API for a tenants Office 365 resources. Can I build this in such a way that the tenant admin is only prompted to grant access to the Graph API when they enable the optional feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you just need to use the new application model. For an example, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2/